# Function giving incorrect result

Tags: java, swing

I know something is wrong with my variables storing the info.

At the end of the program, it prints 0.0 for rate.

I have been trying to figure out the error in logic or syntax in my program. I believe it may have something to do with the variables being 0, I have also tried inserting the function into the loop when count == floor.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class pickanumber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int floor=1, rooms, occupants, rsum = 0, osum = 0;
    String amount;

    do {
      amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter total floors.");
      floor = Integer.parseInt(amount);
    } while (floor <= 0);

    for (int count = 1; count <= floor; count++) {
      if (floor==13) count++;

      do {
        amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter total rooms on floor "+count+".");
        rooms = Integer.parseInt(amount);
      } while(rooms <= 9);

      rsum += rooms;

      do {
        amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter occupants on floor "+count+".");
        occupants = Integer.parseInt(amount);
      } while ((occupants > rooms)||(occupants < 0));

      osum += occupants;
    }

    int rate = (osum/rsum)*100;
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("occupancy is at "+rate+"% capacity.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Run a debugger and step through line by line

Comment: Please do that and are all those while really necessary?

Comment: they were intentional, but no they were not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osum`and `rsum` are both integers, they represent numbers without decimal.

Any math opertion using only those 2 integers will return an integer.

So `osum/rsum` will return

- `0` if `osum < rsum`
- `1` if `rsum <= osum < 2*rsum`
- etc.

If you want to get the decimal value of this division, you can

- define your `rate` as `double` type in order to contain decimal numbers.
- cast at least one of your varaible as a `double` in the operation

You should end with something like:

```
double rate = (((double) osum)/rsum)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the datatypes i guess (or atleast i couldn't think of anything else). the result of `(osum/rsum)` must be integer, and will therefor nearly always be 0 (or 1, if `osum == rsum`). Simply cast them to double before the division, and cast the result of the complete calculation back to integer, and things should work quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Double drsum = (double) rsum;    
Double dosum = (double) osum;
Double rate = (dosum/drsum)*100;
int i = rate.intValue();
```

Comment: int rate= (int) ((((double) osum)/rsum)*100);     // This allows for the division, and then I converted it back to int so that it could be printed in user friendly fashion.